# Can't get jssor jQuery slider to fade

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code clearly states 
`$Fade:true, $Duration:1000` are the variables to put in `_SlideshowTransitions`.  I have done so but cannot for the life of me get a fading action on the pictures.

My page can be seen here:  http://shuksanhealth.compumatter.com/ecore/test.php  and a view source will tell it all.  Having said that, here's the code.

Anyone out there familiar with this product and why this fade transition will not work ?

Answer (score 4):

First I recommend you load jquery before plugin.

Second point I could not find any doc that show that fade work like this. It is not that clear.

Found this code on Github Developer

```
    var _SlideshowTransitions = [
    //Fade
    {$Duration: 700, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1000, $Opacity: 2} }
    ];
```

Source: https://github.com/jssor/slider.js/blob/master/examples-jquery/slider-with-slideshow.source.source.html

Maybe you want to try and modify it instead of using your:

```
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [{ 
            $Duration: 2000, 
            // $Delay: 30, 
            // $Cols: 8, 
            // $Rows: 4, 
            // $Top: true, 
            // $Right: true, 
            // $Bottom: true, 
            // $Left: true, 
             $Fade: true
            // $SlideOut: true, 
            // $Assembly: 2049, 
            // $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, 
            // $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs 
            // $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs 
            }];
```

I did a simple test and it worked

Answer (score 4):

This is how I got it to work:

```
var options = { $AutoPlay: true, $SlideshowOptions: { $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$, $Transitions: [{ $Duration:700, $Fade: true, $Opacity:2 }] } };
```

The documentation is indeed not clear.

Comment: Thank you Leonardo. Very good. This is my final code:

        var jfffoptions = { $AutoPlay: true, $SlideshowOptions: { $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$, $Transitions: [{ $Duration:700, $Fade: true, $Opacity:2 }] } };
        
        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jfffoptions);